# Jquery UI and Bootstrap Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drag-and-drop function simplified in the jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/JDH9/6haMV/13/

I added a Modal button, and now the drag-and-drop doesn't work.

The drag and drop uses the following scripts:

- 1.5.0/jquery.min.js
- 1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js

and the modal button / window uses:

- bootstrap.min.js
- code.jquery.com/jquery.js

Does anyone have an idea to work around this so that my drag-and-drop works as well as, the bootstrap modal?

Here's the javascript code:

```js
$(init);

function init() {

    $('#element_1').data( 'number', 1 ).attr( 'id', 'card'+1 ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );

    $('#slot_1').data( 'number', 1 ).droppable( {
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );

}

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

  if ( slotNumber == cardNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you using such old version of jQuery and jQuery UI? Just using the jQuery that comes with bootstrap along with a current version of jQuery UI would probably solve your problem.

Comment: @Samsquanch - I just tried using only bootstrap.min.js and /jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js  and jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js. This still didnt work. I appreciate any further guidance. These are the two you are suggesting, correct?

Comment: Can you update the demo on fiddle to include the full set of code which reproduces the issue, including the bootstrap libraries, and the modal button.  I don't see one on there, but that's the thing that purportedly broke everything.  There are lots of ways to add a modal.  We need to see what your doing.

Comment: okay I've updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JDH9/6haMV/23/

Comment: @KyleMit - Appreciate it as well. Please let me know if you see another way to do a modal and still have the drag-and-drop function work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6haMV/24/ - I don't see your modal button.

Comment: @Trevor, I couldn't find it either - it's just because it has the class `hidden-xs`.  Make your screen bigger or see the fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

They Shouldn't Impact One Another.

The modal button wasn't visible because it had the class `hidden-xs` and most people are viewing through jsFiddle's narrower result pane.

Other than that, they both should work simultaneously.  If something isn't working, I would first look at your console to see if there are any errors on the page.  Then I'd look at each individually to make sure that both are still working:

This fiddle should work just fine:

### http://jsfiddle.net/6haMV/31/

Comment: thanks. This does work. So you didn't see any other issues with this other than hidden-xs?

Comment: @user25829, There are other code formatting things I could suggest, but since this is now 'working code', I'd accept the answer and move on to a new topic.  If you want help structuring working code, you should post your solution over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to see if they can help improve it.

Comment: thanks again. This is the correct Jquery UI library, right? jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js. I just tried this and got a console error of "Bootstrap's Javascript requires Jquery" and "Jquery is not defined." I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Look at the libraries provided in the fiddle in my answer.  They are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help Kyle. Works now.